# Python 3 tkinter box opened during file prompt won't go away

Tags: python, tkinter

This is all the tkinter I' m using

```
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

file1 = fd.askopenfilename()
file2 = fd.askopenfilename()

data = pd.ExcelFile(file1)
data2 = pd.ExcelFile(file2)
```

It will open the file prompt no problems, but it also opens a small blank tkinter window that won't go away. When I try to close it, it just hangs. Is there a way to get it to close on its own, or not exist in the 1st place?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue in Windows.  If you look into tkinter source code, the implicitly created root window will be hidden initially and be destroyed after the dialog is closed.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was describe long time ago.

It automatically creates main window `tkinter.Tk()` which you see.

You should create it manually and hide it, and later you should destroy it.

```
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

root = tk.Tk()   # create main window
root.withdraw()  # hide main window

file1 = fd.askopenfilename()
file2 = fd.askopenfilename()

root.destroy()   # destroy main window

# -----

if file1:  # check if not `Cancel` selection
    data1 = pd.ExcelFile(file1)
else:
    data1 = None
    
if file2:  # check if not `Cancel` selection
    data2 = pd.ExcelFile(file2)
else:
    data2 = None
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is auto-opening the Tk window. Create it by yourselves so you can modify it and destroy it.

```py
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog as fd

tk = Tk()
tk.withdraw() # do not draw window

file1 = fd.askopenfilename()
file2 = fd.askopenfilename()

tk.destroy() # destroy window

data = pd.ExcelFile(file1)
data2 = pd.ExcelFile(file2)
```

*NOTE: I modified the code so you can actually run it.*

Comment: The `tk.withdraw()` makes the file dialog not open. But If I comment it out, that annoying box will close after the file select does, so it is a fix. Thanks

Comment: @CharlesReed will try to fix it myself

Comment: @CharlesReed fixed! try it out now (the only thing that changed is the first line, i ran the code by myself and now its working as intended)

Comment: also, can you please tell me the error?

Comment: there's no error, the file prompt just doesn't show up. Still doesn't show up with that `tk.withdraw()`, the program is just waiting. But if I remove the line, it works. No clue why it does that

Comment: @CharlesReed same, i'm really sorry man